# Xamarin Android F# update UI in async block

Tags: asynchronous, xamarin, f#, xamarin.android

I'm new to Xamarin, and am trying to build a simple Android app with F#. I'm trying to load in data from a REST API with async, and then display it. I understand that interacting with the UI must be done on the MainThread, and that there is something along the lines of `Activity.RunOnUiThread()`. I've tried the following:

```
let onSearch args =
        let search = this.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource_Id.search)
        let searchResults = this.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource_Id.searchResults)

        button.Text <- search.Text
        async {
            let! results = recipeSearch.GetRecipes search.Text
            searchResults.Text <- results
        }
        |> Async.Start

    button.Click.Add onSearch
```

Which throws the Exception about interacting with the UI elements in another thread.
And this:

```
    let result = async {
                    let! results = recipeSearch.GetRecipes search.Text
                    return results
                }
                |> Async.RunSynchronously
    searchResults.Text <- result
```

Defeats the purpose of doing it Async

Thanks

Comment: Try putting `do! Async.SwitchToContext Application.SynchronizationContext` in your async block before updating `searchResults.Text`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
let onSearch args =
        let search = this.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource_Id.search)
        let searchResults = this.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource_Id.searchResults)

        button.Text <- search.Text
        async {
            let! results = recipeSearch.GetRecipes search.Text
            this.RunOnUiThread(fun () -> searchResults.Text <- results)
        }
        |> Async.Start

    button.Click.Add onSearch
```